# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. What is wrong?

Tags: c#, xna

I have two classes: Game1 and Animation.
I always get that "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error message in this line of the Game1 class: animation.Draw(spriteBatch);
What is wrong? I don't know what to change.

```
Animation class code:
public class Animation 
{            
    private int _animIndex; 
    public TimeSpan PassedTime { get; private set; } 
    public Rectangle[] SourceRects { get; private set; }      
    public Texture2D Texture {get; private set; } 
    public TimeSpan Duration { get; private set; } 

    public Animation(Rectangle[] sourceRects, Texture2D texture, TimeSpan duration) 
    { 
          for (int i = 0; i < sourceRects.Length; i++) 
          { 
                sourceRects[i] = new Rectangle((sourceRects.Length - 1 - i) * (Texture.Width / sourceRects.Length), 0, Texture.Width / sourceRects.Length, Texture.Height); 
          } 

        SourceRects = sourceRects; 
        Texture = texture; 
        Duration = duration; 
    }        

    public void Update(GameTime dt) 
    { 
        PassedTime += dt.ElapsedGameTime; 
        if (PassedTime > Duration) 
        { 
            PassedTime -= Duration; // zurücksetzen 
        } 

        var percent = PassedTime.TotalSeconds / Duration.TotalSeconds; 
        _animIndex = (int)Math.Round(percent * (SourceRects.Length - 1)); 
    } 

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch batch) 
    { 
        batch.Draw(Texture, new Rectangle(0, 0, Texture.Width / SourceRects.Length, Texture.Height), SourceRects[_animIndex], Color.White); 
    } 
}

Game1 class code:
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game 
{ 
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics; 
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch; 
    Animation animation; 
    Texture2D gegner; 
    Rectangle[] gegnerbilder = new Rectangle[10]; 

    public Game1() 
    { 
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this); 
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content"; 
    } 

    protected override void Initialize() 
    {          
        base.Initialize(); 
    } 

    protected override void LoadContent() 
    {            
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice); 
        gegner = Content.Load<Texture2D>("kurzeanim"); 
    } 

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime) 
    { 
        KeyboardState kbState = Keyboard.GetState(); 
        if (kbState.IsKeyDown(Keys.A)) 
        { 
            animation = new Animation(gegnerbilder, gegner, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)); 
            animation.Update(gameTime); 
        } 
        base.Update(gameTime); 
    } 

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime) 
    { 
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue); 
        spriteBatch.Begin(); 
        animation.Draw(spriteBatch);    
        spriteBatch.End(); 

        base.Draw(gameTime); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: `animation` is only initialized in `Update` and not in `Draw`. That's why you get the exception in `Draw`. Use the constructor to initialize fields.

Comment: I can't see how this question will help other readers much in the future. Nice that you got your bug spotted though.

Comment: You are assigning instance of animation conditionally. Can you ensure that your animation object is not null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that the `Update`-method of the `Game1`-class is called before the `Draw`-method of that class or ensure that `animation` is not `null` before calling its members:

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime) 
{ 
    if (animation != null)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue); 
        spriteBatch.Begin(); 
        animation.Draw(spriteBatch);    
        spriteBatch.End(); 
    }
    base.Draw(gameTime); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your field `animation` is not initialized and you are calling its instance method `Draw` that is why you are getting this exception. At that particular line it is null. It is being initialized in update method, you may initialize it in the constructor to avoid that exception

Answer (score 0):

You only ever instantiate the animation property if the A key is depressed when Update is called.

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime) 
{ 
    KeyboardState kbState = Keyboard.GetState(); 
    if (kbState.IsKeyDown(Keys.A)) 
    { 
    animation = new Animation(gegnerbilder, gegner, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)); 
    animation.Update(gameTime); 
    } 
    base.Update(gameTime); 
}
```

You need to initialise it earlier (e.g. in the constructor) or add some logic to the Draw method to check for null values.

Answer (score 0):

`animation = new Animation(gegnerbilder, gegner, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));`

Are you really creating a new animation and updating it every `Update()` That could be 60 Times per second.

You are going to need to add it to your `Initialize()` Method (Or whenever you need to change the animation)

Then in update you can still do animation.Update() but without the constructor.

Comment: I tried it like that but it doesn’t work. It's the first time that I work with properties.    `public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
        Animation animation;
        Texture2D enemy;
        Rectangle[] enemyframes;
        TimeSpan time;

        animation = new animation(Rectangle[] enemy, Texture2D enemyframes, TimeSpan time);`

Comment: Whats that code? Is there an error? Or just not displaying?